# Set value to a class object which is property of another class - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

It's difficult for me to express my problem so I will write a simple example of it. I have 2 classes, MyclassA and MyclassB.

```
@interface MyclassA
@property (nonatomic, assign) int *ID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyclassB *secondclass;
@end

@implementation MyclassA

-(id)init
{
self.ID = 1;
MyclassB *sec = [[MyclassB alloc] init];
sec.age = 10;
sec.weight = 35;
self.secondclass = sec;

return self;
}
```

MyclassB:

```
@interface MyclassB
@property (nonatomic, assign) int age;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int weight;
@end
```

When I place a breakpoint at

```
return self;
```

the value of self.secondclass is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new object of the `MyClassB`. You should initialize the property `secondClass` in the `init` method instead of assigning the reference of another instance of `MyClassB`.

```
-(id)init
{
  self.ID = 1;
  self.secondclass = [[MyclassB alloc] init];
  self.secondclass.age = 10;
  self.secondclass.weight = 35;

  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
MyclassB *sec = [[MyclassB alloc] init];
```

**With**

```
self.secondclass  = [[MyclassB alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.secondclass = [[MyclassB alloc] init];
```

Assign Properly